# How to create a portable VM

Tags: virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, images, portable

I am curious on how to create a portable Virtual Machine image and having it on my phone. I want to be able to take and plug my phone into any computer with Virtual Box (i.e. Windows, Linux, Mac(the Mac not being of great importance)) and boot an Ubuntu, or any other Debian distro, guest from the phone.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are searching for is the *OVF* format. It is a format to save virtual appliances which is open, and independent of system architecture and **hypervisor**. In other words, you will be able to export a VM from your Linux pc running VirtualBox to, say,  a Windows (or Linux, or Mac) machine running VMWare.

The current recognized international standard is 1.1. [This Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Virtualization_Format) article shows which hypervisors support the standard.

You can save a whole VM in *.ova* format by choosing File -> Export Appliance, choose the VM to export, Next -> Format and here you can choose *OVF 0.9*, *OVF 1.0* or *OVF 2.0*.